# Присвоить значение элементу массива

Tags: c++

Только начал изучать С++, возникла сложность. Необходимо присвоить определенному элементу массива значение. Делаю так:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (&inp_str[i] == "=" && &inp_str[i + 1] == "=") {
        out_str[start_out] = "=";
        start_out++;
    }
```

При попытке присвоить значение элементу массива возникла ошибка:

> [bcc32 Error] File1.cpp(18): E2034 Cannot convert 'char const[2]' to 'char'
>   Full parser context
>     File1.cpp(11): parsing: int main(int,char * *)

Как правильно нужно сделать? Спасибо за внимание

Comment: `&inp_str[i]` а зачем тут оператор взятия адреса?

Comment: Если без него то в строке "if (inp_str[i] == "=" && inp_str[i + 1] == "=") {"
возникает ошибка "[bcc32 Error] File1.cpp(17): E2034 Cannot convert 'char' to 'const char *'
  Full parser context
    File1.cpp(11): parsing: int main(int,char * *)"

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ну если я правильно понял то массивы у тебя `char`?

Если да то вот пару ошибок у вас.

Во-первых вы сверяете 1 символ из массива со строкой!
В С++ в двойных кавычках это строка! К ней добавляется завершающий нуль символ.
То есть вы сверяете символ из массива с 2 символами из строки `"="`.
В С++ символ должен быть в одинарных кавычках `'='`.
А то у вас получается что вы сверяете к примеру символ '=' с 2 символами `'='` и `'\0'`.

Во-вторых вы берёте не символ из массива, а пытаетесь получить адрес  адрес ячейки массива в которой хранится символ и сверить со строкой.
Символ `&` в С++ означает взятие адреса.

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (inp_str[i] == '=' && inp_str[i + 1] == '=') {
        out_str[start_out] = '=';
        start_out++;
    }
}
```

У вас в сообщении ошибки так и написано, что компилятор не может с конвертировать символ из массива в 2 символа из строки `"="`, чтобы потом сверить их.

Answer (score 3):

В C/C++ есть разница между одинарными и двойными кавычками. В динарные кавычки заключаются одиночные символы (`char`), а в двойные - строки, массивы символов (`char[]`). Вы берёте i-й элемент массива (`char`) и пытаетесь сравнить его со строкой (а в третьей строке вообще пытаетесь присвоить строук символу). С точки зрения C++ вы сравниваете (и присваиваете) разные типы (символ и массив символов), которые нельзя привести друг к другу (даже несмотря на то, что в вашем массиве всего один символ (на самом деле два, '=' и '\0', нуль-терминатор, отмечающий конец строки)). Для того, чтобы ваш код заработал, нужно брать символ **=** в одинарные кавычки.

Ещё добавлю, что для сравнения строк (массивов символов) в C есть функция `strcmp`. А ещё в C++ есть класс `string`, который позволяет работать со строками более удобно.